# What's the right structure Deep Learning structure for Multilabel classification

Tags: deep-learning

I have the following data

```
         feat_1    feat_2 ... feat_n   label
gene_1   100.33     10.2  ... 90.23    great
gene_2   13.32      87.9  ... 77.18    soso
....
gene_m   213.32     63.2  ... 12.23    quite_good
```

The size of `M` is large ~30K rows, and `N` is much smaller ~10 columns.
My question is what is the appropriate Deep Learning structure to learn
and test the data like above.

At the end of the day, the user will give a vector of genes with expression.

```
gene_1   989.00
gene_2   77.10
...
gene_N   100.10
```

And the system will label which label does each gene apply e.g. great or soso, etc...

By structure I mean one of these:

- Convolutional Neural Network (CNN)
- Autoencoder
- Deep Belief Network (DBN)
- Restricted Boltzman Machine

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that a feedforward Neural Network with 1 or more hidden layers should be appropriate for a binary or multiclass problem.

I should also point out that with a relatively smaller number of features (10) compared to M, other classifiers such as Logistic regression / Random Forests should give acceptable performance and would train faster as well.

Comment: What rationale is your suggestion based upon?